# How to save the image with text in imageview

Tags: android, imageview

Basically my Imageview contains a Image on which i write text dynamically,the problem is i'am able to save only the image, but not the image with text.I tried the following solutions in the questions but it dint work.
[Save image view as a jpeg image in sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228750/save-image-view-as-a-jpeg-image-in-sdcard)
[How can I save the content of an ImageView to a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080324/how-can-i-save-the-content-of-an-imageview-to-a-bitmap-in-android)
The saved image should look something like this
http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2012/07/01/dos-equis-meme_custom-1b9aee77416a2ac82498c4358db1d22a65abe441-s6-c30.jpg

Comment: Please read the pertinent section of the Java spec _fully_ before posting questions like this that can be easily answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [in the same section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9-130), it will have a default access too:

> In a class type, if the class is declared public, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier public (§6.6); if the class is declared protected, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier protected (§6.6); if the class is declared private, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier private (§6.6); **otherwise, the default constructor has the default access implied by no access modifier**.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained on the page you linked (bold mine):

> In a class type, if the class is declared public, then the default
>   constructor is implicitly given the access modifier public (§6.6); if
>   the class is declared protected, then the default constructor is
>   implicitly given the access modifier protected (§6.6); if the class is
>   declared private, then the default constructor is implicitly given the
>   access modifier private (§6.6); **otherwise, the default constructor has
>   the default access implied by no access modifier**.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter. If you do not define explicit constructor the empty public default constructor exist. If you class has fields these fields will remain not initialized when you are creating instance using the default constructor.